# “gelungen”, “mehr gelungen”, “meisten gelungen” – is this correct comparative?

Tags: grammaticality, comparison

> Die Arbeit ist ihm gelungen.
>
> Die Arbeit ist ihm mehr gelungen.
>
> Die Arbeit ist ihm am meisten gelungen.

Are then above comparatives correct? *Mehr gelungen* is a pretty frequent term, but the meaning seems to be pretty convertible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don’t esteem *mehr gelungen* to be grammatically correct. It’s better to use *besser:*

> Die Arbeit ist ihm besser gelungen.
> Die Arbeit ist ihm am besten gelungen.

Possible, too (with *Arbeit* meaning the work’s result):

> Die Arbeit ist gelungener als ...
>
> Die Arbeit ist am gelungensten.

But the second example is used in written language mostly in my opinion.

It’s possible to use *meister/meiste/meistes* (superlative of *viel)* if you want to say that the work was only partially successful:

> Die meiste Arbeit ist ihm gelungen.

But this means that the work **wasn’t completely successfully**, so it’s **less** than: “Die Arbeit ist ihm gelungen.” And it’s better to formulate this in a totally different manner (without *meiste*), namely:

> Ein (großer) Teil der Arbeit ist ihm gelungen.

The difference is that *gut – besser – am besten* describes the object’s overall **quality**, compared to another object. *Viel – mehr – am meisten* denotes **quantity**.

Answer (score 1):

**No, they're not.** [Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=gelungen) says

> ADJ -      gelungen | gelungener | am gelungensten ...
>   <sub>http://www.dict.cc/?s=gelungen</sub>

But I'd say that **gelungen** is not used that often for comparison, though you can do it.

Probably more common is it to strengthen or weaken it, e. g.

> Das ist ihm [wirklich/absolut/definitiv] gelungen
>   Diese Arbeit ist ihm [nicht so gut/eher weniger/kaum/gerade so] gelungen.

But note the nuances of those adverbial qualifications.